# Replace < with &lt; everywhere but inside backticks

Tags: perl

I have a multiline `$string` which contain code. I would like to replace all the `<` and `>` chars with `&lt;` and `&gt;` everywhere but inside the backticks.

Example:

```
Here a < and a ` some foo < stuff`
```

Output:

```
Here a &lt; and a ` some foo < stuff`
```

What is the easiest way to implement it in Perl?

Comment: what have you tried? There's several ways to iplement that, and a lot of these would be considered easy by different people.

Comment: Can the backticks enclose more than just a `<` sign, or is the sequence always *backtick*, *less-than*, *backtick*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried with a simple regex to match ouside paired backticks recursively. The code is horrible. Another way was to parse the string once, extract non greedy backticked string, replace them with a marker, do the `&lt;` substitution everywhere and restore the backticked strings.

Comment: @Borodin You lost me

Comment: @coin: Borodin asked: "Is it always `\`<\``, or can it also be `\`<stuff\``?"

Comment: @coin: sounds like you have two solutions already... Why don't you mention these in your question? Otherwise, the next best guy would just suggest your horrible regex...

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are right. I should have implemented these first then ask my question after all

Comment: Okay, so can the closing backtick be on a new line after the opening one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined your problem very well, but this replaces all `<` signs that are neither preceded immediately nor followed immediately by a backtick.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  s/(?<!`)<(?!`)/&lt;/g;
  print;
}

__DATA__
Here a < and a `<` and Here a < and a `<`
Here a < and a `<`
```

**output**

```
Here a &lt; and a `<` and Here a &lt; and a `<`
Here a &lt; and a `<`
```

---

**Update**

Okay, so you can have any data inside the backticks, including newlines (I think, but you seem reluctant to say) which is much easier to handle if you read the whole file into a scalar variable.

This works by finding all backtick-enclosed substrings or less-than signs `<`, and replaces the former by itself and the latter by `&lt;`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>;
};

$data =~ s{ ( `[^`]*` ) | < }{ $1 // '&lt;' }egx;
print $data;

__DATA__
Here a < and a ` some foo < stuff`
Here a < and a ` some foo <
stuff`
Here a < and a ` some foo < stuff`
```

**output**

```
Here a &lt; and a ` some foo < stuff`
Here a &lt; and a ` some foo <
stuff`
Here a &lt; and a ` some foo < stuff`
```